# Unexpected PSQLException using `returning`

Tags: java, jooq

I am writing an insert method in my DAO, taking advantage of PostgreSQL `returning` support.

```java
public Vendor insert(final Vendor pojo) {
  final VendorRecord record = dsl.newRecord(VENDOR, pojo);

  record.setDateCreated(OffsetDateTime.now());
  record.setCreatedBy("TODO");

  return dsl
      .insertInto(VENDOR)
      .set(record)
      .returning(VENDOR)
      .fetchOneInto(Vendor.class);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: jOOQ; SQL [insert into "public"."vendor" ("id", "name", "description", "url", "date_created", "created_by", "date_updated", "updated_by") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning "public"."vendor"."id", "public"."vendor"."name", "public"."vendor"."description", "public"."vendor"."url", "public"."vendor"."enabled", "public"."vendor"."date_created", "public"."vendor"."created_by", "public"."vendor"."date_updated", "public"."vendor"."updated_by", "public"."vendor"."version"]; A result was returned when none was expected.

    at org.jooq_3.18.4.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.translate(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.handle(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqExceptionTranslator.exception(JooqExceptionTranslator.java:55)
    at org.jooq.impl.ExecuteListeners.exception(ExecuteListeners.java:304)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:372)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQueryAsResultQuery.fetch(AbstractDMLQueryAsResultQuery.java:140)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchLazy(ResultQueryTrait.java:281)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchLazyNonAutoClosing(ResultQueryTrait.java:290)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchOne(ResultQueryTrait.java:509)
    at org.jooq.impl.ResultQueryTrait.fetchOneInto(ResultQueryTrait.java:533)
    at com.oliveryasuna.finance.backend.persistence.repository.VendorRepository2.insert(VendorRepository2.java:42)
    at com.oliveryasuna.finance.backend.persistence.repository.VendorRepositoryTests.insertOne(VendorRepositoryTests.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkNoResultUpdate(PgStatement.java:280)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:109)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.executeReturningGeneratedKeys(AbstractDMLQuery.java:1264)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:1223)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:357)
    ... 77 more
```

Here is the DDL for the `vendor` table:

```sql
create table vendor
(
    id           uuid                     not null
        constraint vendor_pk
            primary key,
    name         varchar(50)              not null,
    description  varchar(255),
    url          varchar(2048),
    enabled      boolean                  not null default true,
    date_created timestamp with time zone not null,
    created_by   varchar(50)              not null,
    date_updated timestamp with time zone,
    updated_by   varchar(50),
    version      integer                  not null default 0
);
```

And I don't use any fancy jOOQ configuration except to generate POJOs.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the stacktrace:

```
 at org.jooq_3.18.4.DEFAULT.debug(Unknown Source)
```

That `DEFAULT` means `SQLDialect.DEFAULT`, which isn't the right configuration to work with PostgreSQL. Use `SQLDialect.POSTGRES` instead.

Comment: New to jOOQ, so didn't think much of that. Turns out I forgot to set it in my Spring test. However, now my returned POJO has `null` for all fields. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, silly mistake. Should have done `returning(VENDOR.fields())`